# making a GET request from within a <script> tag in my index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, express

i am writing an app with angular.js client side and node express server side.

i am using in my server side staticAsset module.

in my index.html i have a long list of javascript files that needs to be downloaded:

```
<script src="lib/angular/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/routingConfig.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/DateCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-underscore.js"></script>
...
```

and so the list goes on.

i would like to first make a GET call to my server and retrieve all the fingerPrints for my static files so then i could actually load each one of them like:

i figured maybe something like this:

this prompts error on my client:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/fingerPrints".
```

but i succeed in going to my server and retrieving an array of all the fingerPrints which should replace the real URLS. in any case i don't know how to pass them to the left  tags.

how should i implement this?

thanks.

Comment: if you are asking how to dynamically load js files and dependency management Google `require.js`

Comment: I think some of your code might have disappeared from your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to node.js and express, but it seems to me your nearly there.

I think all you have to do is set the content type of your response like so:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
```

hope it helps!